# Conversion of Infix expression to Postfix

Tags: c++

Below is the program i have written to convert a infix expression to postfix. It does give an output but its not always the right one. For example if we input the expression **A+B*C-D/F+G** , the expected output is ABC*+DF/G+- but rather the program outputs **AB+C*D-F/G+**. What is the problem in the program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
 
int prec(char oper){
    if(oper == '^')
      return 3;
    else if(oper == '*' || '/')
      return 2;
    else if(oper == '+' || '-')
      return 1;
    else
      return -1;
}
 
string itp(string s){
  stack<char> stack;
  string output = "";
  int num = s.length();
 
  for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++){
    char ch = s[i];
 
    if((ch>='a' && ch<='z')||(ch>='A' && ch<='Z')||(ch>='0' && ch<='9'))
      output = output + ch;
 
    else if(ch == '(')
      stack.push('(');
 
    else if(ch == ')'){
      while(stack.top()!='('){
        output = output + stack.top();
        stack.pop();
      }
      stack.pop();
    }
 
    else{
      while(!stack.empty() && prec(s[i]) <= prec(stack.top())){
        output = output + stack.top();
        stack.pop();
      }
      stack.push(ch);
    }
    }
  while (!stack.empty()) {
  output = output + stack.top();
  stack.pop();
  }
 
  return output;
}
 
 
int main(){
  string question;
  cout<<"Enter the infix expression : ";
    cin >> question;
    cout<<endl<<"Postfix expression : "<<itp(question);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string.h` is a "problem". The header for `std::string` is called `string`

Comment: "the expected output is ABC*+DF/G+-" Nope. `if(oper == '*' || '/')` This is wrong, `||` doesn't work this way.

Comment: `||`, like `&&`, is a binary operator. `x == a || b` means "either x is equal to a, or b is 'true'", not "x is equal to either a or b".

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: @re4per `if((ch>='a' && ch<='z')||(ch>='A' && ch<='Z')||(ch>='0' && ch<='9'))` -- This is not the way to test for alphabetic or digit characters.  Use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`.  Not every system uses ASCII, and even if it uses ASCII, there are locales that have additional alphabetic characters that are not in the ranges you are testing for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
else if(oper == '*' || '/')
```

you are using `||` wrongly. If you consider operator precedence (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you will see that `==` has higher rank than `||`, hence it is parsed as

```
else if( (oper == '*') || '\')
```

The first part will evaluate to `true` or `false` but as `\` is not equal to `0`, it will be `true` always, hence in total the condition is `true` always.

What you want is

```
 else if( oper=='*' || oper=='\')
```